# How to parse ONLY the JSON value returned by CURL in PHP?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, curl

I am able to successfully make a send POST values through CURL but I can't seem to figure out how to get the only the JSON code it returns.

Here is a part of my code:

```
try {
    $curl = curl_init($url);

    if (FALSE === $curl)
        throw new Exception('failed to initialize');

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array("Content-type: application/json")
    );          
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");   
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

    $message = curl_exec($curl);

    if (FALSE === $message)
        throw new Exception(curl_error($curl), curl_errno($curl));

    $response = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $error = $message;

    var_dump($error);
    curl_close($curl);

} catch(Exception $e) {
    trigger_error(
        sprintf(
            'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
            $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()
        ),
        E_USER_ERROR
    );
}
```

I am able to get the correct value for the $response variable but the returned message gives me:

```
string(253) "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Cache-Control: no-cache Pragma: no-cache Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Expires: -1 Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5 Date: Sun, 02 Jul 2017 17:47:34 GMT Content-Length: 38 {"Message":"Email is already in used"}"
```

when I try to use var_dump. What I am aiming to store for me error message variable it the value for Message that is in {"Message":"Email is already in used"}

Any tips?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you tried to json encode after the cURL has been executed?

Comment: "400 Bad Request" suggests to me that the server is not processing your request because of a client error. Does the endpoint definitely accept POST requests? Does the $data variable contain all required fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Cache-Control: no-cache Pragma: no-cache Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Expires: -1 Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5 Date: Sun, 02 Jul 2017 17:47:34 GMT Content-Length: 38
```

Are the headers returned by the cURL request.
You'll have to set `CURLOPT_HEADER` to `FALSE` (`0`) to remove the headers from the output:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
```

As stated by the [documentation](https://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) when `CURLOPT_HEADER` is `TRUE` headers will be included in the output.

Comment: Ahhhh this is such a small detail I missed. Thanks a lot!